# Opencart - Instant update quantity in cart

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencart

For standard opencart behavior, after adding the product in cart, user needs to click to update button manually for quantity update. For sample, please refer to http://demo.opencart.com/. However, I would like to change to when I change the quantity, the cart info can be refreshed immediately. I've tried following code but it doesn't work:

1. For catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/cart.tpl, I updated:

> button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-primary">
>   i class="fa fa-refresh">/button>

(don't know why I cannot paste the code properly on the above line. I've removed some < to make it show)

to

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onchange="cart.update('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
```

2. In catalog/view/javascript/common.js

There is a function

```
var cart = {
  //skip some lines for other function
    'update': function(key, quantity) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<img src="image/catalog/content/cart/quote-icon.png" alt="quote"><span class="badge badge-giftu rounded-x">' + json['totallines'] + '</span>');
                }, 100);

                if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                } else {
                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            }
        });
    },
}
```

I tried if I change to cart.remove under the on.change function, it works. However, it doesn't work for cart.udpate. Is there anyone know what is the issue of triggering the ajax update issue?

Comment: you can do like when you update quantity use ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

I myself had such a problem solved it like this

Old code (i have custom them):

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" size="1" class="form-control"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"
        onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
```

New Code (fixed) look on input and Remove(button type="button" If he also does not work)

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" 
       size="1" class="form-control"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" 
            class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"
            onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
```

There was a problem that incorrectly gave the notation for the fields it was necessary to put the key in the cart_id